# How to use Capybara to check error messages from Simple Form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, simple-form

I have the following test:

```
scenario 'with invalid attributes' do
  click_button 'Create Post'
  save_and_open_page
  expect(page).to have_content 'Post has not been created.'
  expect(page).to have_content 'Title can\'t be blank.'
  expect(page).to have_content 'Content can\'t be blank.'
end
```

And `_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= simple_form_for(post) do |f| %>
  # post passed to simple_form_for is @post
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :content %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: 'button' %>
<% end %>
```

In order to have the full error message, `config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb` has this:

```
b.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
```

And model `post`.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :content, presence: true
end
```

When I run `rspec`, I get:

```
expected to find text "Title can't be blank." in "Post has not been created. new post * TitleTitle can't be blank * ContentContent can't be blank"
```

The `save_and_open_page` shows:

```
<div class="form-group string required post_title has-error">
  <label class="string required control-label" for="post_title">
    <abbr title="required">*</abbr> Title
  </label>
  <input class="string required form-control" type="text" value="" name="post[title]" id="post_title" />
  <span class="help-block">Title can&#39;t be blank</span>
</div>
```

Why is Capybara not considering any whitespace between the `<label>` and `<span>`?

Comment: you have a full-stop in your capybara spec: `'Title can\'t be blank.'` the error message is showing you that the full-stop is not there: `TitleTitle can't be blank ` remove it from your spec and it should pass.

Comment: Oh my! Yes, that was it. I  didn't even look to the period in the end of the message. I could only see the `TitleTitle can't...`. Thanks! Do you want to please answer this so I can accept your answer? :)

Comment: heh - I've done the same thing myself, which is why I know to look for it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's just a small mistake. You have a full-stop in your capybara spec:

```
expect(page).to have_content `Title can\'t be blank.'
```

Whereas the error message is showing you that the full-stop is not there:

```
TitleTitle can't be blank
```

remove it from your spec and it should pass :)